# При ресайзе задавать высоту элементу в px

Tags: javascript, dom

Я хотел бы, чтобы при ресайзе элементу задавалась высота в px, всё нормально работает, если просто уменьшаешь экран, но если увеличить экран, высота остаётся той, что сжалась. Как сделать так, чтобы высота уменьшалась при увеличении экрана?

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];

items.forEach((item) => {
  let height;
  resize();

  function resize() {
    height = item.scrollHeight;
    item.style.height = height + 'px';
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
<div class="item">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio labore voluptatibus tenetur quasi, fugit aliquam id quo et libero. Exercitationem temporibus inventore id voluptatem illum ipsam sed? Non nam at fugiat, nobis officiis veniam neque commodi
  ab eligendi, nisi minus aliquid accusantium, placeat soluta exercitationem? Facilis dicta quia inventore ducimus eum ex, dignissimos iusto animi aliquam, debitis iure cum consectetur. Debitis reiciendis sint dolor quas, quaerat earum incidunt error.
</div>
<div class="item">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio labore voluptatibus tenetur quasi, fugit aliquam id quo et libero. Exercitationem temporibus inventore id voluptatem illum ipsam sed? Non nam at fugiat, nobis officiis veniam neque commodi
  ab eligendi, nisi minus aliquid accusantium, placeat soluta exercitationem? Facilis dicta quia inventore ducimus eum ex, dignissimos iusto animi aliquam, debitis iure cum consectetur. Debitis reiciendis sint dolor quas, quaerat earum incidunt error.
</div>
<div class="item">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio labore voluptatibus tenetur quasi, fugit aliquam id quo et libero. Exercitationem temporibus inventore id voluptatem illum ipsam sed? Non nam at fugiat, nobis officiis veniam neque commodi
  ab eligendi, nisi minus aliquid accusantium, placeat soluta exercitationem? Facilis dicta quia inventore ducimus eum ex, dignissimos iusto animi aliquam, debitis iure cum consectetur. Debitis reiciendis sint dolor quas, quaerat earum incidunt error.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:
Задать элементу `height: auto`, у элемента автоматически посчитается высота, взять её и задать элементу в px

```
item.style.height = 'auto';
height = item.scrollHeight;
item.style.height = height + 'px';
```

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];

items.forEach((item) => {
  let height;
  resize();

  function resize() {
    item.style.height = 'auto';
    height = item.scrollHeight;
    item.style.height = height + 'px';
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio labore voluptatibus tenetur quasi, fugit aliquam id quo et libero. Exercitationem temporibus inventore id voluptatem illum ipsam sed? Non nam at fugiat, nobis officiis veniam neque commodi
    ab eligendi, nisi minus aliquid accusantium, placeat soluta exercitationem? Facilis dicta quia inventore ducimus eum ex, dignissimos iusto animi aliquam, debitis iure cum consectetur. Debitis reiciendis sint dolor quas, quaerat earum incidunt error.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio labore voluptatibus tenetur quasi, fugit aliquam id quo et libero. Exercitationem temporibus inventore id voluptatem illum ipsam sed? Non nam at fugiat, nobis officiis veniam neque commodi
    ab eligendi, nisi minus aliquid accusantium, placeat soluta exercitationem? Facilis dicta quia inventore ducimus eum ex, dignissimos iusto animi aliquam, debitis iure cum consectetur. Debitis reiciendis sint dolor quas, quaerat earum incidunt error.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio labore voluptatibus tenetur quasi, fugit aliquam id quo et libero. Exercitationem temporibus inventore id voluptatem illum ipsam sed? Non nam at fugiat, nobis officiis veniam neque commodi
    ab eligendi, nisi minus aliquid accusantium, placeat soluta exercitationem? Facilis dicta quia inventore ducimus eum ex, dignissimos iusto animi aliquam, debitis iure cum consectetur. Debitis reiciendis sint dolor quas, quaerat earum incidunt error.
  </div>
</div>
```